# The computer said a game was drawn but I think it is won for me

Tags: endgame, stalemate

It's white's move and the king can't move.

Why was this game drawn? I should have won it I think.

[image]

Comment: There are three ways to win a chess game: by checkmate, by time, and by forfeit. None of those have happened here.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the site. What you described is the definition of stalemate, not checkmate. The enemy king not being able to move anywhere (while it's not attacked) is stalemate. That's why the game was drawn.

For a checkmate, you'd need to trap the king *and* be attacking it at the same time.

If it seems weird that stalemate is a draw, you're not alone. The 3rd world champion Capablanca argued that stalemate be considered a win. Nevertheless, the rules of chess dictate otherwise.